# coco2D CCLayer's init function

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a label which I like to add on to the scene,

```
     -(id) init{
     yourScore=[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" dimensions:CGSizeMake(50, 30) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:20];        
    yourScore.position=ccp(230, 250);
    [self addChild:yourScore];}
```

However if I add the CCLabel somewhere else like

```
    -(void) addlabel:(NSString*) string_
       { yourScore=[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" dimensions:CGSizeMake(50, 30) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:20];        
    yourScore.position=ccp(230, 250);
    [self addChild:yourScore];}
```

which this addlabel function is being called to add the label. now the youScore label is not shown up on the game. That makes me wonder why it needed to add inside the -(id) init function to make it shown?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, when you init an empty CCNode, it's contentSize is 0,0 and it keeps it that way after adding children.

Can you check the contentSize of your CCScene for both cases?

if it's different you can either use a different position for your label, or even better change the Scene's contentSize manually before adding any children. Personally, I prefer setting the contentSize to the screen's size

Btw, you should call [super init] too, in the init body

Comment: contentsize?  both are 320x480 before and after.

Comment: Are there any other children added to your Scene, except the 'yourscore' label ?